# Multivariate polynomial representations of the infinite dihedral group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials

The presentation given in Wikipedia for the [infinite dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group) is

$$\langle r,s\mid s^2 =1, srs = r^{-1}\rangle.$$

Let $[R]$ denote the infinite set of reciprocal partition polynomials $R_n(u_1,u_2,...,u_n)$ (signed OEIS [A263633](https://oeis.org/A263633) under suitable normalization) defined by the multiplicative inverse, or reciprocal, of an o.g.f.

$$\frac{1}{1+ u_1 x + u_2 x^2 + \cdots} = 1 + R_1(u_1) x + R_2(u_1,u_2) x^2 + \cdots.$$

Let $[N]$ denote the infinite set of noncrossing partition polynomials $N_n(u_1,u_2,...,u_n)$ (essentially OEIS [A134264](https://oeis.org/A134264)) defined by the compositional inverse of a shifted reciprocal

$$ \left (\frac{x}{1 + u_1x + u_2 x^2 +\cdots } \right )^{\langle -1\rangle}  = x(1 + N_1(u_1) x + N_2(u_1,u_2) x^2 + \cdots).$$

Under the group operation of substitution of the polynomials of one set for the indeterminates of another, for example, let $[N][R]$ designate the set of polynomials $N_n(R(u_1),R_2(u_1,u_2),...,R_n(u_1,...,u_2))$ for $n=1,2,3,...$, then $[R]=s$ and $[N]=r$ are the generators of an infinite dihedral group with $[R][R] = [R]^2 = [I]$, the identity under substitution, and $[R][N][R] = [N]^{-1}$, the inverse under substitution of $[N]$.

The above is based on the fairly arbitrary coefficients of power series, or ordinary generating functions (o.g.f.s). Another set of generators $[P]=s$ (essentially OEIS A133314) for the reciprocal of Taylor series, or exponential generating functions (e.g.f.s), and $[E] = r$, the set of refined Eulerian partition polynomials (OEIS A145271) are available.

1. Are there other multivariate polynomial reps of the infinite dihedral group with integer coefficients?

Finite dihedral groups are used to characterize aspects of the Coxeter group of type A (see, e.g., "[Generalized Noncrossing Partitions and Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611106)" by Drew Armstrong). One member of the group above is the set $[A] = [N][R]$ of refined Euler characteristic partition polynomials of the associahedra (essentially re-normalized OEIS A133437).

2. What literature comprehensively integrates the algebraically oriented infinite-dihedral-group perspective above with the geometrically oriented finite-dihedral-group perspective of Armstrong?

Comment: Another way to think of this is as an action of the infinite dihedral group on formal power series with constant term 1. We define maps $r$ and $s$ on such formal power series by $s f(x) = 1/f(x)$ and $r f(x) = \bigl(x/f(x)\bigr)^{\langle -1\rangle}$. Then $s^2=1$ and $srsr=1$.

Comment: @IraGessel, yes. By looking only at the substitution operation of partition polynomials, the graded nature of the algebra of multiplicative and compositional inversion becomes obvious and the issue of convergence of power series vanishes. $sr$ translates into the conjugation $[R][N]= [R][A][R] = [A^{(-1)}] = [N]^{-1}[R]$ in my nomenclature in other notes and $[A^{(-1)}]^2=[I]$, the identity substitution, where the superscript $(-1)$ here labels one member of the infinite set of involutions $[N][A^{(m)}] = [A^{(m+1)}]$ for $m$ any integer and $[A^{(0)}]=[R]$.